# object required error when comparing text in cell (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a few of if statements to check multiple cells to see if they're the same (checks quantity in column C, and if they're the same, checks text in column D. If both pass, marks the row in column C).

I'm getting problems with this line specifically.

```
     If (aSht.Range("D" & i).Text = b.Sht.Range("D" & j).Text) Then
```

I looked up strcompr but it didn't seem to be what I wanted. Is there a better way to compare two strings in an If statement, or does something need to be declared earlier for text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra period in your statement. Remove the period from `b.Sht`.

Comment: If you put Option Explicit at the top of your module, it'll catch errors like this. I always end up turning this on after the first time I mistype a variable.

Comment: I didn't know about Option Explicit. That'll help a lot. Thanks again!